# While loop to create object. User can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError).

Tags: ruby, class, object, methods, typeerror

Hello below is some ruby code I have been working on in an effort to learn the language.  My goal for this code is to create new users while i is less than the set limit.  I have a feeling I am going about this the wrong way but I figured I would ask in order to learn the best practice to do something like this.

I am getting an error once the method has run it's course and the loop does not continue to make users.  Instead I get this error message.

```
ruby.rb:16:in `+': User can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)
from ruby.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

I am able to create one user but the loop does not continue to make users as intended.  Any insight would be appreciated.  Thank you.

```
class User
    def initialize
        puts "What is your name?"
        name = gets.chomp
        puts "What is your email?"
        email = gets.chomp
        puts "Your name is #{name} and your email is #{email}"
    end
end

i = 0
limit = 5

while i < limit do
    i+=
    User.new
end
```

Comment: Did you mean `i+=1`? BTW, ruby way to write such a loop would be `5.times { User.new }`

Comment: You are doing well. Change your `i+=` to `i+=1` like BroiSatse said. It should work.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't notice the error there.  I can see how 5.times would be more eloquent than a while loop.  Thanks.